# Simple Function does not work, dont see the error

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

I am a beginning python programmer, but have written several scripts including ones in which I define my own functions and use them.  I cannot seem to get any user defined functions to work within the IDLE.  Wondering if I am crazy/dumb.  Can somebody please explain the following results?Thanks:

```
def f(x,y):
    solution = x+y
    return solution
f(2,2)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = f(2,2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    a = f(2,2)
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

---

```
def g(x):
    solution = x + 2
    return solution
g(2)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = g(2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    a = g(2)
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a blank line after the definition of the function to make the interpreter understand that it's finished.

```
>>> def f(x,y):
        solution = x+y
        return solution

>>> f(2,2)
4
```

Comment: Man, edited AND beat me to the answer - I'd +1 twice if I could :)